# Deployed bytecode size seems to mismatch contract code size

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

I See some very weird solc behaviour with regards to compiled bytecode size.
A much shorter contract compiles to bigger byte code.

[short contract](https://gist.github.com/ilanDoron/d9b4451ef9be0d717c2696cef1151b03): compiles into 439 bytes.
while [this longer one](https://gist.github.com/ilanDoron/beca019f5861a94337a0db12027d2657) compiles into 129 bytes.
note that the longer contract includes the code of the shorter one plus some extra code.

not sure what am I missing.

Answer (score 1):

Thank to Kamil Śliwak that replied to me on the solidity gitter channel.

reason is the longer contract has only internal functions which the optimizer will remove out of the deployed bytecode.
must call the functions of switch to external in order to check bytecode size effects.